# Do all transactions have at least one output that contains at least one bitcoin address

Tags: transactions, address, output

Do all transactions that are included in a valid block have to have at least one bitcoin address as part of their outputs (vout)?

I found this to be similar: [Are Bitcoin transactions permitted to have no outputs (i.e. all inputs become transaction fee)?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12451/are-bitcoin-transactions-permitted-to-have-no-outputs-i-e-all-inputs-become-tr) although not quite the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  A notable example of a pubkey script that doesn't typically include addresses or keys is the [nulldata standard transaction type](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#null-data).  Examples of pubkey scripts that include public keys but not addresses are [pay-to-pubkey (P2PK)](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#null-data)[1] and ["bare" multisig](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#null-data).

Although I'm not absolutely sure, I believe its allowed to have an empty pubkey script.  (That is, the compactSize uint that describes the size of the pubKey script is 0x00.)

Note: Bitcoin Core's `getrawtransaction` RPC, `decodetransaction` RPC, and other RPCs will display the public keys in P2PK, bare multisig, and redeem scripts as addresses---which can be a bit confusing.

[1] P2PK was formerly used for most coinbase transactions, but that usage has mostly disappeared on mainnet with pooled mining.  It's still a standard transaction type and quite common for coinbase transactions on testnet.

Comment: Great answer David, thanks! Do all transactions have to have at least one output amount (value)?

Comment: You're welcome.  All transactions must have at least one output.  All outputs must have a value, but that value can be 0 satoshis.  For example, in order to be standard, a nulldata standard transaction must have a value of 0.

Comment: +1 for the additional note, been banging my head against the wall due to this for hours.